# Notice: Undefined index on SqlWalker.php

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

This is my Categorias model: http://pastebin.com/Wk5iw3Hf
and
this is my Proyectos model: http://pastebin.com/LDTpZ3Cy

One Category has many proyects.

In my repository, I´m trying to join this models, like this:

```
public function findMistareas() {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $consulta = $em->createQuery('SELECT c, p FROM GestionBundle:Categorias c JOIN c.proyectos p ');
        return $consulta->getResult();
}
```

but I´m getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: Categorias in /Users/gitek/www/ges/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/SqlWalker.php line 747
```

any help or clue? Maybe the problem is on the Model? but I can not see where.

Comment: I think you are missing the "Gitek" part in your entity namespace:
`SELECT p, h FROM GitekGestionBundle:Proyectos`

Comment: No, it isn´t necesary to add Gitek part... but thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categorias",inversedBy="proyectos")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoria_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $categoria;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Hitos", mappedBy="Proyectos")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"orden" = "ASC"})
 */
private $hitos;
```

'SELECT p, h FROM GestionBundle:Proyectos p JOIN p.hitos h '

Your question is about categories but your query uses hitos?  The mappedBy and inversedBy are case sensitive so probably need mappedBy="proyectos" instead of mappedBy="Proyectos"

Comment: Yap! Sorry! I just updated de code right now. I will try with Hitos later. First thins first: Categorias and Proyectos... I checked my Model an the name is in Uppercase and the table name also is un uppercase

Comment: The mappedBy refers to a member variable name, not an entity class.  Those are in lower case, at least for what you posted.  Different issue: having a member name such as $category_id as part of a relation is also a bit alarming.  It should probably be $category since it holds an object and not just an id.